# Building runnable jar using onejar-maven-plugin

Tags: java, maven, onejar

How can I make it build regular artifact not containing "one-jar" in the name?
I am using following settings in my POM:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.jolira</groupId>
    <artifactId>onejar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.4</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>package.ClassName</mainClass>
                <onejarVersion>0.97</onejarVersion>
                <attachToBuild>true</attachToBuild>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>one-jar</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: To be clear, you're still wanting a fat jar, you just don't want `one-jar` added to the file name?

Comment: Yes, just the file name change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<configuration>
  <filename>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.${project.packaging}</filename>
</configuration>
```

or, any other pattern you would like.

Answer (score 0):

just add

```
<configuration>    
    <classifier>WhatEverStringYouWant</classifier>
</configuration>
```